# Silent uninstallation without any window with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall an application installed with Inno Setup from another Inno Setup installer. I am able to find the uninstall string from the registry but I am not able to execute it silently. I am using `RemoveQuotes()` function of Inno Setup as below:

```pascal
RunProcess(RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString), '/SILENT');
```

But it the uninstaller window is still visible.

Where `RunProcess()` method is given as:

```pascal
function RunProcess(name : String; args : String) : Integer;
var
  path : String;
  dir : String;
  errorCode : Integer;
begin
  path := ExpandConstant(name);
  dir := ExtractFileDir(path);
  Log(' Running: ' + path + ' ' + args + ' ...');
  Exec(path, args, dir, SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, errorCode);
  if errorCode = 0 then
    Log(' Succeeded.')
  else
    Log(' Failed. Error Code: ' + IntToStr(errorCode));
    
  Result := errorCode;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

To run an uninstaller, built in Inno Setup, without any window, use `/VERYSILENT` [command-line parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstcmdline):

> When specified, the uninstaller will not ask the user for startup confirmation or display a message stating that uninstall is complete. Shared files that are no longer in use are deleted automatically without prompting. Any critical error messages will still be shown on the screen. **When '/VERYSILENT' is specified, the uninstallation progress window is not displayed.**
>
> If a restart is necessary and the '/NORESTART' command isn't used (see below) and '/VERYSILENT' is specified, the uninstaller will reboot without asking.

---

You may also consider using `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` parameter.